# Maintain 2 indexes or separating the complex and simple indexes in searchkiq / elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, reindex, searchkick

Hi I am using searchkiq gem for elastic search.
I got a situation where I need to maintain the indexes which will be used for normal situation and some indexes in only for requested scenario that might come or not. 
The properties I want to index as primary and secondary. Primary will be indexed on callbacks etc. And secondary will be indexed only on demand, say from console or any button from admin panel.

How can I accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Searchkick automatically reindexes your ActiveRecord after commit.

To disable this:

```
searchkick callbacks: false
```

And to reindex on demand, you can just call `YourModel.reindex`

Comment: That I know, i want two indexes one with callbacks and another manual

Comment: 1. two elasticsearch indexes for the same model?

2. or two ways to index your data to the same elasticsearch index?